# Why am I getting incorrect WBTC when swapping it with DAI using Uniswap?

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, erc20, uniswap

Hi I created a smart contract but when I swapped **1 Million DAI** token I am getting only **~3379786784 WEI (~34 WBTC)** but when I am checking its value on UNISWAP website it is showing **43 WBTC**.

I am using **ganache-cli with mainnet fork**. Using **truffle** to test the smart contract.

**test-uniswap.js**

```
const BN = require("bn.js");
const IERC20 = artifacts.require("IERC20");
const TestUniswap = artifacts.require("TestUniswap");

contract("TestUniswap", (accounts) =>{
    const DAI = "0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F";
    const DAI_WHALE = "0xF977814e90dA44bFA03b6295A0616a897441aceC";
    const WBTC = "0x2260FAC5E5542a773Aa44fBCfeDf7C193bc2C599";

    const WHALE = DAI_WHALE;
    const AMOUNT_IN = new BN(10).pow(new BN(18)).mul(new BN(1000000));
    const AMOUNT_OUT_MIN = 1;
    const TOKEN_IN = DAI;
    const TOKEN_OUT = WBTC;
    const TO = accounts[0];

    it("should swap", async ()=>{
        const tokenIn = await IERC20.at(TOKEN_IN);
        const tokenOut = await IERC20.at(TOKEN_OUT);
        const testUniswap = await TestUniswap.new();
        console.log(`outbefore ${await tokenOut.balanceOf(TO)}`);

        await tokenIn.approve(testUniswap.address, AMOUNT_IN, {from: WHALE});

        await testUniswap.swap(
            tokenIn.address,
            tokenOut.address,
            AMOUNT_IN,
            AMOUNT_OUT_MIN,
            TO,
            {
                from:WHALE,
            }
        );

        console.log(`out ${await tokenOut.balanceOf(TO)}`);
    });
});
```

**TestUniswap.sol**

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8;

import "./interfaces/IERC20.sol";
import "./interfaces/Uniswap.sol";

contract TestUniswap{
    address private constant UNISWAP_V2_ROUTER = 0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D;
    address private constant WETH = 0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2;

    function swap(
        address _tokenIn, //Token trading in for
        address _tokenOut, //Token that we want
        uint256 _amountIn,
        uint256 _amountOutMin,
        address _to
    ) external{
        //Transferring the token to this contract that we want to swap
        IERC20(_tokenIn).transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _amountIn);
        IERC20(_tokenIn).approve(UNISWAP_V2_ROUTER, _amountIn);

        address[] memory path;
        path = new address[](3);
        path[0] = _tokenIn;
        path[1] = WETH;
        path[2] = _tokenOut;

        IUniswapV2Router(UNISWAP_V2_ROUTER).swapExactTokensForTokens(
            _amountIn, 
            _amountOutMin, 
            path, 
            _to, 
            block.timestamp);
    }
}
```

Whole project
https://github.com/vinayprolitus/uniswap

Comment: Also the UI might route the trade differently across different pools to optimise the price impact.

Comment: I could have understood if there was a little difference but its around 10 WBTC less than the actual number.